# Is it easy to get an UberX from Central London to Heathrow Airport?

Tags: london, lhr, ride-sharing, uber

I'd like to get an uberX to heathrow airport because I'm rushing, but I'm not sure how difficult it will be. Do drivers normally decline jobs there?

Comment: You can move the pin inside uber app to central London and check how many taxis around... That will give you an overview..

Comment: I have a feeling your question might be unanswerable since it'll be hard to find statistics from authoritative sources.

Comment: If you're in a rush, then a black cab might be better. Black cab drivers have to know all the streets in London, the best ways between then, fastest options etc. I've generally found Uber drivers in London friendly, but largely unaware of where things are, and utterly reliant on satnavs...